# word files opening with only one click

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

All word files are opening with only one click. It is only with word and nothing else. Folder Options is set to 2 clicks. I have tried restore defaults in folder options as well.

Using Office 2010 on Windows 7

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Can you clarify?

Comment: There might not be a question mark, but it seems fairly clear that he wants to know why his Word files are opening with a single-click, whereas everything else seems to open with a double-click.

Comment: Thank You Josh. Yes, why is it doing this and how do I get it back to the way it was, double click for word as well as every thing else?

Answer (score 0):

1. Type "Folder" in your search bar
2. You can see "File Explorer Options"
3. Click on it.
4. In general tab find "Click Items as follows"
5. Select on single click option and close window
6. You will see all your files are underlined
7. Go back to "File Explorer Options" and tick Double click options
8. You are done. Review the files