# Excel Files Opn On 1 Click - Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

[word files opening with only one click](https://superuser.com/questions/670559/word-files-opening-with-only-one-click) 
I have come across this same issue, but its with Excel, not Word. By simply selecting the file it opens up. The 'Click items as follows' option is set to "Double click to open", so that's not the issue.

Its a hassle particularly when you want to copy files over, they stat opening when you select them.
What can be causing this? It was not like this before and the option to D-Click is correctly selected.

- Windows 10 Pro up to date
- MS Office Pro 2016 MSO all updates V 2201 (Build 16.0.14827.20198 32-Bit)

Comment: Note: When He said "Same issue" , He was reffering to [this Question](https://superuser.com/questions/670559/word-files-opening-with-only-one-click)

Comment: Does this issue occur with other files that do not use Office apps to open? I would suggest you [repair Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) first to have a check.